# select onchange firing twice in ie7

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

this is really wierd, not sure why this is happening but my onchange is firing twice. any help/ideas is greatly appreciated...

```
<select id="ddlGender" onchange="myfunc()">
  <option value="1">-select-</option>
  <option value="2">Male</option>
  <option value="3">Female</option>
  <option value="4">NotSpecified</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Can we see the code for myfunc()?

Comment: Could you post the content of myfunc? Perhaps you are changing the selected index of ddlGender in myfunc and triggering another onchange that way?

Comment: Does anything else trigger change events programatically with jQuery? There's a jQuery bug that can cause exactly this behavior in that case; let me go search the bug database.

Comment: Are you using your mousewheel to scroll down the page after you select your option? The mousewheel can really cause havoc with select onchange functions as it will cause them to fire repeatedly.

Comment: [Here is the jQuery bug I logged.](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/6593) I don't know whether this is relevant to your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your java script code should be in java script file loaded in your head:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#ddlGender").unbind('click').change(myfunc);

  var myfunc = function (e)
  {
    // Do something important....
  }
});
```

If I remember correctly you need to unbind click event from select in IE in order to avoid firing event twice.

And your html should not have onchange any more:

```
<select id="ddlGender">
  <option value="1">-select-</option>
  <option value="2">Male</option>
  <option value="3">Female</option>
  <option value="4">NotSpecified</option>
</select>
```

Comment: That's not really solving the problem, that's merely suggesting how one might refactor the code. I assume the given example in the question uses inline JavaScript for simplicity.

Comment: If you look closer, there is unbind('click') before change that should actually solve this particular problem.